# How do I grep in a list of files targeted by a previous grep?

Tags: linux, grep

I am using grep to get a list of files that I want to use for another grep search (and not simply piping it).

For example I got as an output:

```
file1.h:XXX: linecontent
file2.h:XXX: linecontent
file3.h:XXX: linecontent
file4.h:XXX: linecontent
```

and I want to grep only file1.h, file2.h ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to search for files that contain two different patterns. If so this is what you want:

```
grep 'your pattern 2' `grep -l 'your pattern 1' *`
```

The contents of the back quotes will be executed first and the output substituted into the command line. Use of the -l flag will restrict the output of the grep command to just the file names.

If there are a very large number of files that match against `your pattern 1` this could fail. The solution for that is to use xargs

```
grep -l 'your pattern 1' * | xargs grep 'your argument 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is the names of files that contain 'lineofcontent', you could use:

```
grep -l 'lineofcontent' file*.h
```